# GTK3 compilation won't find GLib2.0, which I actually compiled. What am I missing?

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, ubuntu-16.04, gtk3, glib

The last days I struggled with libraries ([GLib2.52.2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/glib2.html) & [GTK3.22.15](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html)), while I tried to compile them on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (fresh installation).

The **GLib2.52.2 just compiled** without errors after installing the needed dependencies.

My problem is following:

when I want to start compilation of GTK3.22.15

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pcre=system && make -j 6
```

I get this error message:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.49.4    atk >= 2.15.1    pango >= 1.37.3    cairo >= 1.14.0    cairo-gobject >= 1.14.0    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.30.0) were not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.49.4' but version of GLib is 2.48.2

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

## SOLVED EDIT

I got a suggestion from AskUbuntu to compile everything in `/usr/local` to prevent conflicts, in some cases with official repository updates.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pcre=system && make -j 6
```

Did solve my problem under these conditions. I didn't touch anything more, referring to the other so said "not matching" dependencies, to compile **GTK3** (3.22.15) *after recompiling* **GLib2.0** (2.52.2)  in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0):

> Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.49.4' but version of GLib is 2.48.2

When compiling libraries for Gnome or `Gtk`, you frequently have to update other libraries too. If you download `gtk3` from the `ubuntu` repositories (use the `synaptic` package manager to search for `gtk3` or `gtk+-3.0`), you will see that you will not only download `gtk3`, but a pile of other libraries `gtk3` needs. In case of using the repositories (recommended!) the system will take care of everything.

I'm not an Ubuntu user, but I am interested in the behind-the-scenes part, so I frequently compile libraries, and I have to do this manually. So, to install a new version of `gtk3`, I have to first compile and update  `glib`. After doing so, I might also have to update `Pango`, `ATK`, and several other libraries first. If you like losing time with such stuff, go for it! Else consider using the repositories.

Comment: I linked the required GLib Version in the first sentence and already compiled it as mentioned, but thanks for your reply. As I talked to another person, I got suggested, to compile everything in `/usr/local` to prevent conflicts - and in this case it just worked fine.

Comment: "/usr/local to prevent conflicts" doesn't actually guarantee everything goes well. But I'm glad it did in your case. Keep in mind for the future that you have mixed up the install paths though (most distributions I know use /usr as path).

Comment: I see. But if I would want to have 2 different libraries, one as default and the other for special processes, how do I generally accomplish that?

Comment: Though I've never done it myself, I think that you could use several libraries, even of the same mayor version, if you specify the minor version in the compilation. So, where normally you'd link to libxxx.so, you could specify libxxx.so.1, libxxx.so.2 etc, explicitly. Even libxxx.so.1.1 and libxxx.so.1.2. in the latter case, `ldconfig` would make libxxx.so.1 point to libxxx.1.2 (the newest version), but you can always link to libxxx.so.1.1 the hard way. I would not recommend it though.